# I am trying to access and operate(shutdown/restart) a remote PC from my pc using SNMPget/set commands

Tags: snmp, mib, oid

After enabling the SNMP service in my pc as well as the remote pc, on trying to restart a remote PC tried using snmpset which resulted either in -

===

snmpset : Timeout

No response from <<IP address/ hostname>>

===

Can you also specify the OID to restart **DELL precision tower 7910**

The command which was tried to restart is as follows :

```
"snmpset -c public <<ip address/ hostname>> <<OID for restart : 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.1.1.0>> i 1"
```

the above command was expected to restart the remote pc which unfortunately did not restart or provide any response. which only resulted in timeout issue or no response.

Comment: For Linux or Windows machines, remote control typically go through SSH/PowerShell. Don't waste your time on SNMP.

Comment: can you give more insights on how do i go on with SSH/Powershell to restart or perform any operation in remote PC.

Answer (score 0):

This `snmpset -c public` looks like an SNMP v1 credential, which will grant you *read only* access. You should use the SNMP v2c credentials in order to send `set` commands.